# XCode Bot Error: "internal-post-timeseries-error"

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server, xcode-bots

I've got the new OSX Mavericks Server set up to run the tests for my iOS project through a Bot.  While the build and the tests to run and everything passes just fine, the actual integration is reported as a failure. The following error appears several times towards the end of the bot's log file:

```
[https]Request{XCBotService.updateBot:({
    guid = "c5e4cf65-5a99-5a99-6ac7-e19d4fd9600f";
    latestFailedBotRunGUID = "46c2cc1f-2c0d-4613-901a-3285ccf7c4cf";
    latestRunStatus = failed;
    latestRunSubStatus = "internal-post-timeseries-error";
})}
```

Does anyone know what that means or how to resolve it?

Comment: I dont have THIS error even but a similar one

Comment: Same error here! It looks like, the server is trying to update the bot... But why this? I don't know, and why is it happening? No clue!    [XCSBuildHelper.m:97 7af9f310 +0ms] Updating bot run with GUID 3e611ab1-1219-42b4-8a5f-f841d9734c5a
    Feb 14 16:59:55 castle-black.local xcsbuildd[13156] <Debug>: [XCSBuildHelper.m:102 7af9f310 +0ms] Updating bot run (3e611ab1-1219-42b4-8a5f-f841d9734c5a): {
     guid = "3e611ab1-1219-42b4-8a5f-f841d9734c5a";
     status = failed;
     subStatus = "internal-post-timeseries-error";
 }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462329/all-xcode-bots-tests-pass-but-why-does-it-fail-integration-with-no-tests-found