# All Xcode Bots Tests Pass, but why does it fail integration with "No tests found"?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5.1, xcode-bots

I run xcode bots with 188 tests and they all pass, but it shows a failure on the bot web page:

[image]

You can also see that running the bots again pass.  The failures happen intermittently but it is not rare.

The Summary tab shows that the failing integration has no results:
[image]

Also, all the tests pass, seen here:
[image]

I did find this in the build log:

```
Mar 13 13:04:11 testowlmacmini.local xcsbuildd[97650] <Error>: [XCSBuildBundle.m:787 756b6310 +0ms] Got an error from the post timeseries data operation: Error Domain=XCSBuildServiceDomain Code=-1 "Error posting build timeseries data for e9859e8a-ec4b-43ae-be30-5fe6ef8dce13 (Remote service call failed: Response{0ms succeeded=0 responseStatus=failed response=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7fefa40588f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fefa2f4b7c0 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:4443/svc, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:4443/svc, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}})" UserInfo=0x7fefa4443580 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error posting build timeseries data for e9859e8a-ec4b-43ae-be30-5fe6ef8dce13 (Remote service call failed: Response{0ms succeeded=0 responseStatus=failed response=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7fefa40588f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fefa2f4b7c0 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:4443/svc, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:4443/svc, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}})}
    Mar 13 13:04:11 testowlmacmini.local xcsbuildd[97650] <Debug>: [XCSOperation.m:28 756b6310 +0ms] Cancelling operation: XCSPostTimeseriesDataOperation
    Mar 13 13:04:11 testowlmacmini.local xcsbuildd[97650] <Error>: [XCSBuildBundle.m:559 756b6310 +0ms] Got an error posting timeseries data: Error Domain=XCSBuildServiceDomain Code=-1 "Error posting build timeseries data for e9859e8a-ec4b-43ae-be30-5fe6ef8dce13 (Remote service call failed: Response{0ms succeeded=0 responseStatus=failed response=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7fefa40588f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fefa2f4b7c0 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:4443/svc, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:4443/svc, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}})" UserInfo=0x7fefa4443580 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error posting build timeseries data for e9859e8a-ec4b-43ae-be30-5fe6ef8dce13 (Remote service call failed: Response{0ms succeeded=0 responseStatus=failed response=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7fefa40588f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fefa2f4b7c0 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:4443/svc, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:4443/svc, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}})}
```

Xcode 5.1

What went wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553382/xcode-bot-error-internal-post-timeseries-error?rq=1